# Analysis Services Tabular Model - New Calculated Table (with DAX) grouping by Weeks

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017, expression, dax, analysisservices

I am creating an AS Tabular Model in VS2017.
I imported the table I needed from a SQL DB server by creating an expression with the next structure:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    ...
WHERE   ...
GROUPBY ...
```

The table has a DATE column.
In my AS Tabular Model I would like to create a calculated table (using DAX) with the same columns but this time grouping by week, so all the totals are summarized.

How can I achieve this?
I'll like to avoid creating another expression for this as I am trying to optimize the report I already created by directly querying the SQL DB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual approach is to create a calendar table with a week attribute, create a relationship to your table. Then allow analysis services to do a summary by on the fly when you tell it to (by selecting week in your client tool). Then if performance is not acceptable you might want to consider pre creating a summary table. In other words.. analysis services already does this on the fly and you don't usually need to specifically create a summary table. Summary tables make things kinda complicated because users have to know which is the right able to use

Comment: Great to hear that.